# create new pandas column is other column contains a string

Tags: pandas, contains

I have:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': {0: 'success', 1: 'failed', 2: 'variable x 10', 3: 'variable xr 134', 4: 'error', 5: 'not found'}})
```

I want to create 3 columns depending on if a substring is present in the main column.

- if the column contains the word `variable`, then I want to split the string and take the 2nd element
- if the column contains the word `variable`, then I want to split the string and take the 3rd element. this value can also be a string
- if the column contains one of these key words, `success`, `fail`, `error`, or `not found`, then I want to place a key word of `Success`, `Fail`, or `Error`.
- if none of the keywords are present, then I would like a `None` or `''` to appear

I tried:

```
df['var']=np.where(df['col1'].str.contains('variable'), df['col1'].str.split(' '),'')
df['val']=np.where(df['col1'].str.contains('variable'), df['col1'].str.split(' '),'')
df['other']=np.where(df['col1'].str.contains('not found'|'error'),'Error',
                     np.where(df['col1'].str.contains('success'),'Success',
                              np.where(df['col1'].str.contains('fail'),'Fail','')))
```

but I get the error `unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'` with the `str.contains` and cannot select specific portions of the split string, as I receive the error  `operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (6,) (3,) ()` when trying `df['val']=np.where(df['col1'].str.contains('variable'), df['col1'].str.split(' ')[2],'')`

Pictorially, this is what I would like to end up with
[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) each of the three portions (*if any*), then [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) the whole thing :

```
others = {
    "success": "Success", "fail": "Fail",
    "error": "Error", "not found": "Error"
}

pat_vax = r"variable\s+(?P<var>\S+)\s+(?P<val>\S+)"
pat_oth = r"(%s)" % "|".join(others)

out = (
    pd.concat([
        df, df["col1"].str.extract(pat_vax),
        df["col1"].str.extract(pat_oth, expand=False)
            .map(others).rename("other")], axis=1
    )
)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

               col1  var   val    other
0           success  NaN   NaN  Success
1            failed  NaN   NaN     Fail
2     variable x 10    x    10      NaN
3  variable xr 134r   xr  134r      NaN
4             error  NaN   NaN    Error
5         not found  NaN   NaN    Error

[6 rows x 4 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace` to create columns like a csv file then extract fields:

```
dmap = {
    'success': ',,Success',
    'failed': ',,Fail',
    'error': ',,Error',
    'not found': ',,Error',
    'variable\s+([^\s]+)\s+(.*)': r'\1,\2,',
    '^(?!success|failed|error|not found|variable).*$': ',,'
}

cols = (df['col1'].replace(dmap, regex=True)
                  .str.extract(r'(?P<var>.*),(?P<val>.*),(?P<other>.*)'))
out = pd.concat([df, cols], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
               col1 var   val    other
0           success            Success
1            failed               Fail
2     variable x 10   x    10         
3  variable xr 134r  xr  134r         
4             error              Error
5         not found              Error
6           nothing
```

Comment: thank you, but the `'variable\s+([^\s]+)\s+(.*)': r'\1,\2,',` bit is not being interpreted in my python, so does not work

Comment: Did you set `regex=True`?

Comment: my python won't even let me define `dmap` bc of that line. Tried changing from `'` to `"`, but no effect. FYI working in VSCode